# Mongoid Mongo High Availability Connection Issues

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, high-availability

Last week one the server hosting our primary replica set imploded.  MongoDB did well, it failed over and promoted a secondary to the primary.  However, our applications continued to try and connect to the down server.  This forced a 60s timeout every time a user tried to connect to the old db, before it would timeout and try the next one.

Here is our setup.

Mongo Setup

- 3 Replica Sets
- v2.4.13

Mongoid Setup

- moped-2.0.7
- mongoid-4.0.2

mongoid.yaml

```
  production:
    default:
      hosts:
        - db1:27017
        - db2:27017
        - db3:27017
      database: test
      options:
        read: :primary_preferred
        write: {'w': 1}
        pool_size: 200
        pool_timeout: 15
        max_retries: 30
        retry_interval: 1
        refresh_interval: 5
        timeout: 15
```

I understand the initial delay.  When a server drops out like that, it takes a bit of time to sort that out.  What I don't undersand is why it continues trying to connect to the primary?

Any ideas?

thanks.
myles.

Comment: all the preferences of secondary,secondary_preferred, primary, primary_preferred, and nearest are for read ops only. write *has to* goto primary. while mongoid may not recognize the new master (unless rebooted?). if your "every time a user tried to connect to the old db" involves a write, such as updating a timestamp then its plausible its stuck on finding the old master for the write. try reading only on login.

Comment: ah your config is missing a heartbeat_frequency. ismaster is the command for checking each node for their master status.
# Changes the default time in seconds the server monitors refresh their status via ismaster commands
        heartbeat_frequency: 1

Comment: also you are missing a replica_set: config. i get the feeling this is being treated as 3 indie dbs opposed to a rs. (at least from the point of view of mongoid)

Comment: I've done some more research, and have figures out what is happening, but I still don't know how to fix it.  The primary server fails and the replica set fails over to a new server.  The connection time out is 10s, the heartbeat checks every 10s.  The heartbeat waits 10s before giving up.   Then tries again.  During that time, nothing can connect to the database.  I just need to find the right combo of time outs and frequency to keep to failover well, without to much down time.